# Scipy installation cygwin64 Windows10 fails at late stage

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, cygwin, windows-10

Installed cygwin64, including Python 2.7, on my new computer running Windows10.

Python runs fine, adding modules like matplotlib or bitstream goes fine, but when trying to add scipy the build eventually, after about an hour, having successfully compiled lots of fortran and C/C++ files,  fails with:

`error: Setup script exited with error: Command "g++ -fno-strict-aliasing -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wimplicit-function-declaration -fdebug-prefix-map=/usr/src/ports/python/python-2.7.10-1.x86_64/build=/usr/src/debug/python-2.7.10-1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/usr/src/ports/python/python-2.7.10-1.x86_64/src/Python-2.7.10=/usr/src/debug/python-2.7.10-1 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -Iscipy/spatial/ckdtree/src -I/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c scipy/spatial/ckdtree/src/ckdtree_query.cxx -o build/temp.cygwin-2.2.1-x86_64-2.7/scipy/spatial/ckdtree/src/ckdtree_query.o" failed with exit status 1`

I've tried both pip install and easy_install, both result in the same error.

Greatful for any hints on what to try next.

Answer (score 3):

I suffered for days with the same issue. My final solution was to install scipy0.15.1: pip install scipy==0.15.1. Hope it works for you too.

Answer (score 2):

I found this while looking for a solution to the same problem but I could not downgrade to 0.15.1 as suggested because of 1.16 dependencies.

The problem is related to infinity having been defined twice in the official v0.16.1 but it only seems to cause issues for a couple platforms.

It was fixed in this commit. https://github.com/scipy/scipy/commit/832baa20f0b5

You should be able to download and compile the master branch from here on cygwin: https://github.com/scipy/scipy

I just finished installing numpy,scipy,scikit-learn,theano on cygwin.